# renderDataTable single row selection is not working

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I am trying CRUD operations in a data table using APIs.For the Edit part, once the particular row has been updated , renderDataTable **single row** selection is not working based on observeEvent. surprisingly, for ***selection = "none"*** renderDataTable Works. Looking forward to work around to resolve this issue.

Here is the part of code in server.R :

****Edit Button and ObserveEvent:****

```
output$EditButton = renderUI({
row_count <- input$dataTable_rows_selected
if (length(row_count)!= 0) {
tags$div(
  actionButton("Edit", "",icon("edit"),style="color:rgb(57,156,8);border-   color:rgb(255,255,255)"),
  bsTooltip("Edit","Edit",trigger = "hover"),

  tags$b(bsModal("edit_final11","Edit Data","Edit",size="small",
                 tags$div(
                   textInput("attribute_edit11","Attribute(*)",value=info_data11[row_count,1]),
                   textInput("value_edit11","Value(*)",value=info_data11[row_count,2]),
                   textInput("unit_edit11","Unit(optional)",value=info_data11[row_count,3]),
                   actionButton("Edit_AB","OK")
                 )))
)
}
})

observeEvent(input$Edit_AB,{

toggleModal(session, "edit_final11", toggle = "close")

row_count <- input$table2_rows_selected

if(exists("movingpath_home")){
responseData2_home<-iListImage(HOST,PORT,USERNAME,PASSWORD,ZONE,movingpath_home)
}
else{
responseData2_home<-iListImage(HOST,PORT,USERNAME,PASSWORD,ZONE,homePath)
}

responseDataFilter2_home<-responseData2_home
displayableData<-as.data.frame(responseDataFilter2_home, stringAsFactors =     FALSE, row.names = NULL)
ObjectName <- as.character(displayableData[row_count,1])
ObjectPath <- as.character(responseData2_home[row_count,5])

dataPath <- paste(ObjectPath,"/",ObjectName,sep = "")

data_row_count <- input$dataTable_rows_selected

source("updateSpecificdata.R")
res_edit<-   updateSpecificdata(dataPath,info_data11[data_row_count,1],info_data11[data_row_count,2],info_data11[data_row_count,3],input$attribute_edit11,input$value_edit11,input$unit_edit11)
session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'alertmessage',message =res_edit)

info_data11<<-iListdata(dataPath)

if(class(info_data11)=="data.frame"){
output$dataTable<-DT::renderDataTable({

  responseDataFilter<-info_data11
  displayableData<-as.data.frame(responseDataFilter, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL)
},server = TRUE,selection = "single",

escape=FALSE,options=list(paging=FALSE,searching = TRUE,ordering=FALSE,scrollY = 400,scrollCollapse=TRUE),rownames=FALSE)
}
else{
session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'alertmessage',message =info_data)

}
})
```

Comment: would be better if you could share a running app where the error is reproducible,...

Comment: @BigDataScientist Hi...As the app have running API which have needs authentication so its not possible to share an example outside the work environment.That why, pasted the sanitized version of the same.